# How to build regex beginng with [a-z][A-Z] and ending with digits

Tags: regex

The front part is letters `[a-zA-Z]` (**necessary**), and the back part is digits (**optional**). total length `>=1 && <= 80`.

Should match the following:

```
a
a1
ab12
aAc
aAd12
```

Should **not** match following:

```
1
1a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: How is `a1` a match if `[a-z][A-Z]` is _mandatory_?

Comment: Try  [`^[a-zA-Z]+\d{0,80}$`](https://regex101.com/r/EIsPMS/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Then how is `a1` a match?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the line.

To match a lower or uppercase character one or more times you could use `[a-zA-Z]+` followed by matching a digit 0 - 80 using a quantifier `\d{0,80}`

[`^[a-zA-Z]+\d{0,80}$`](https://regex101.com/r/EIsPMS/1/)

Edit:

If the total length should be 1 -80 you could use a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=` to assert that what follows is `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,80}`until the end of the line `$`

Then match one or more times a lower or uppercase character `[a-zA-Z]+` followed by zero or more times a digit `[0-9]*`.

[`^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,80}$)[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/u0DkJI/1)

Comment: Wasn't it the total length that was supposed to be 1 - 80 not only the digit part?

Comment: @S.H.N In that case the OP could use a positive lookahead [`^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,80}$)[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/u0DkJI/1)

Comment: Yeah. It should be total length. It's appreciate if you can update in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In order to limit the whole length to 80:

```
^(?i)(?=.{1,80}$)[a-z]+\d*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : beginning of line
  (?i)          : case insensitive
  (?=.{1,80}$)  : positive lookahead, make sure we have 1 upto 80 characters
  [a-z]+        : 1 or more letters
  \d*           : 0 or more digits
$               : end of line
```

Comment: Instead of `(?=.{1,80}$)` could probably also be used `(?!.{81})` but does not make much difference.